# call jquery function within a php loop

Tags: php, jquery, loops, foreach

I have this JS function:

```
function count_messages_in_thread( convo_id ) {
$('#conversation_' + id ).load('counter.php', {
    conversation_id: id
});
}
```

which gets called within this php loop (*rough* copy):

```
foreach ( $threads as $thread ) { 
echo "<script>$(function() { count_messages_in_thread( '" . $thread->convo_id . "' ); });</script>";
echo "<div id='conversation_" . $thread->convo_id . "'></div>";
}
```

As you may guess, this function counts and shows the number of (unread) messages in forum threads (its a single page app therefore I use JS for this purpose)

I would like to separate PHP and JS. I was thinking about making an array with IDs using php and then passing it to JS to get through and then pass its variables to corresponding DIVs.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 3):

Passing the data to JavaScript is exactly what I'd suggest.

```
<script>
  var threads = <?php echo json_encode($threads); ?>;
</script>
```

Whenever you pass data to JavaScript, use `json_encode()` to make sure all the types and escaping are done for you.  From there, you can handle everything you need to do in JavaScript.